# Getting out of memory exception on Ignite cache for select query

Tags: ignite

I have turned ON SQL support for my ignite cache and I am running a simple sql query with a LIMIT clause and getting an out of memory exception.

Below is the stack trace:

```
org.apache.ignite.client.ClientException: 
  Ignite failed to process request [3513]: 
   Failed to execute map query on remote node [nodeId=c288da2b-a3fb-4752-8c6e-4b2f88470bef, errMsg=Out of memory.; 
   SQL statement:
     SELECT
     __Z0._KEY __C0_0
     FROM "cache".__Z0 LIMIT 200 [90108-197]] (server status code [1])
```

My ignite memory is configured to 8 gb and I'm fetching only key records from the table and not the values.
I am not sure what is causing this error.
Any lead would be very helpful.

Comment: What's your Ignite configuration? I mean, there are 2 memory configurations to take care of: offheap and Java heap. Check your Ignite metrics if you are not sure what values are, the line should be like this: ^-- Heap [used=2135MB, free=93.48%, comm=32768MB]

Comment: Hey Alex Thanks for the pointer, i checked the logs and i see ignite metric 20 seconds before i got the out of memory exception - ^-- Heap [used=5618MB, free=31.42%, comm=8192MB]
    ^-- Off-heap memory [used=3179MB, free=63.01%, allocated=8396MB] So it appears that it had free memory?

Comment: Yes, here you can see that 1/3 of your heap was free. And you should also see that "free" metric is decreasing before the crash. I think, in this case, you better want to get this resultset in a lazy fashion, check this documentation for details https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/sql-tuning#lazy-loading

Comment: Also what Ignite/GridGain version are you using? In GG edition there is a memory quota feature that might help as well https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/sql-tuning#lazy-loading